# Unable to update plot border width in highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Originally I have the plot border width set as 0 and then later I want to update it as per below. But it doesn't work. The tooltip part works and I believe the attribute is in the correct place.

```
chart.update({
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
       },
       plotBorderWidth: 1
});
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `plotBorderWidth` property in a `chart` object:

```
chart.update({
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9pcm0fon/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBorderWidth

Comment: Yes, I've just realised myself. Thanks for the answer!